# How to use torsocks with GUI apps?

Tags: linux, firefox, gui, tor

`torsocks` is a command that forces programs to use Tor. I tested its effectiveness by curling a site that returns my external IP.

```
$ torsocks curl ip.me
109.70.100.1
```

Then I searched the IP on the official Relay Search website to confirm that curl indeed used a Tor Exit Node.

https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/109.70.100.1

https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/5788CEC0A7C5EE251FC72C55730A6B1FCAEA1D93

I was given node 'ruebe' in Austria.

After the successful experiment I wondered if I could run vanilla Firefox through Tor. I know Tor Browser is the recommended browser but some websites just don't work in it. First I made sure Firefox was functional.

```
$ firefox
(Firefox opens)
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs
```

Throws two warnings but otherwise works.

Then I tried running it through Tor.

```
$ torsocks firefox
```

It was running forever but no window opened. Is torsocks not meant to be used with GUI or does it require more configuration? If torsocks is not compatible with GUI apps, what is the right way to run Firefox through Tor?

Answer (score 0):

Best way of using tor is with torbrowser bundle, but if you need to use firefox for this. Consider using `proxychains`.

make sure that **/etc/proxychains.conf** contains line with

> socks5 127.0.0.1 9050

Some other options are firefox extensions like foxyproxy-standard

Answer (score 0):

`torsocks` is not the way to go, for Firefox at least. It will not handle UDP and right now for example [it will abort on IPv6 name resolution](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/torsocks/-/issues/40011) whether you use IPv6 or not, that might be what blocks it.

`torsocks` uses preloading, but it doesn't implement everything. So, for example, `chromium` will fail with `WARNING torsocks: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 234.` and exit.

You can set the proxy inside Firefox settings. Choose SOCKS5 and point to the same server as you did in torsocks.conf.

Then you can switch proxies with an extension, with a [PAC file](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/proxy-pac-i2p-onion.html) or set up different profiles and start with `firefox --profile path` for example.